# Validate if either control is selected on aspx page with DevEx controls

Tags: asp.net, validation, devexpress, client-side

I'm currently working on a web-based survey and am having trouble figuring out validation on multiple DevEx controls. In this particular example, I have a ASPxRadioButtonList, an ASPxCheckBox and an ASPxButton to submit the answer for that page. I need the validation to basically say if either the radiobuttonlist or the checkbox have an answer, then IsValid. I know how to add validation to the radiobuttonlist and checkbox independently, but this then means that both are required when I need either/or.

```
<dx:ASPxRadioButtonList ID="rbRating10" runat="server" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/DevEx/{0}/styles.css"
                CssPostfix="DevEx" SpriteCssFilePath="~/App_Themes/DevEx/{0}/sprite.css" 
                Width="151px">
                <Items>
                    <dx:ListEditItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" />
                    <dx:ListEditItem Text="No" Value="No" />
                </Items>
                <%--<ValidationSettings CausesValidation="True">
                    <RequiredField ErrorText="Required" IsRequired="True" />
                </ValidationSettings>--%>
                <ValidationSettings ValidationGroup="answered"></ValidationSettings>
                <Border BorderStyle="None" />
            </dx:ASPxRadioButtonList>
            <br />
            <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="NoAnswerBox" text="Guest did not answer" runat="server" 
                style="margin-left: 12px" CheckState="Unchecked">
<ValidationSettings ValidationGroup="answered"></ValidationSettings>
            </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
        </div>        
        <div style="width: 100%px; margin: 15px auto 50px auto;">
            <div style="width: 160px; margin: 15px auto 0 auto; float: right;">
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnFwd" runat="server" 
                    CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Aqua/{0}/styles.css" CssPostfix="Aqua" 
                    onclick="btnFwd_Click" SpriteCssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Aqua/{0}/sprite.css" 
                    Text="next question" Width="150px">                    
                </dx:ASPxButton>
```

I have been trying to figure it out as a Client Side Event within the ASPxButton tag, but I don't even know where to start having never done them before. I'm what you may call, a n00b. Below is my attempt, but I really have no idea if this is even the right direction.

```
<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
    var valid1 = NoAnswerBox.GetChecked();
    var valid2 = rbRating10.GetSelectedItem();

    if(valid1==&quot;True&quot; || valid2&gt;=0){
    e.IsValid = True;   
    }
}" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```